# Camera calibration for OpenCV seems to be wrong

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

Please, help me to understand this behaviour.

While camera calibration using this code:

```
Calib3d.calibrateCamera(objectPoints, imagePoints, savedImageSize, intrinsic, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs,
                Calib3d.CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT +
                Calib3d.CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST +
                Calib3d.CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO +
                Calib3d.CALIB_FIX_K4 +
                Calib3d.CALIB_FIX_K5
                ,term);
```

using 45 images which looks like this:
[image]
I'm receiving this:
[image]
that obvoiusly is not correct.

the resultant values:

> ```
>   [26384.00145168781, 0, 1631.5;       0, 26384.00145168781, 917.5;        0, 0, 1]
>   [-33.54856921170454, -0.2057610950119468, 0, 0, 0]
> ```

how can I setup my calibration in order to retrieve correct data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that pure c++ opencv project gives right results using the same properties and code.
this code works: 
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/calibration.cpp

Be careful using java opencv libraries!